# can't find extension_dir in php.ini

Tags: php

I am trying to locate where extension_dir is being set.  I've looked in the loaded configuration file (cli and web) but it's not in there.  However, phpinfo and php -i both show a value that is set.

Is there a fallback default value for when the dir is not explicitly set in php.ini?

Thanks

Comment: check /usr/lib/php5/extensions/

Comment: Your OS environment is required to answer this ... please review posting guidelines. We are not fortune tellers.

Comment: This is under Mac OS X. I know where the extensions are located, I'm just not understanding why extension_dir is showing up in the configuration output while it's not in my php.ini file. Thanks for the replies.  
I'm guessing according to "Michel Feldheim's" answer below, that defaults are used when extension_dir is not explicitly set.

Answer (score 1):

What linux distribution you have ? You can search by modules:

eg:

```
shell ~ # php -m 
[PHP Modules]
gd
hash
.....
shell ~ # find /usr -name gd.so
```

Comment: @cale_b, Can't post comments with 1 rep, unfortunately.

Comment: The default value is set at compile time